# Bind variables to callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm calling some database functions from my request handlers. All of these functions do separate "error callbacks" for handling errors. Example:

```
function referralComplete(req, res) {
    /*getting id etc.*/
    db.startDatabaseConnection(function() {
        db.flagReferralAsDone(id, function(success) {
            db.endDatabaseConnection();
            /*doing stuff on success*/
        }, onError);
    }, onError);

    function onError(err, description) {
        logger.error(description + ": " + err);
        user.pageNotFound(req, res);
    }
}
```

I have several request handlers similar to this all calling different database functions. At the moment I have duplicated `onError()` into the scope of each of them since I need `req` and `res` when handling the error, but I like think that there might be a way to achieve the same without the duplication.

**So the question is**, would it be possible to somehow bind `req` and `res` to `onError()` so that I won't have to duplicate `onError()` into each request handler?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Binding is simple!

```
db.startDatabaseConnection(function(){
  // whatever
}, onError.bind(this, var1, var2));
```

[You can learn more about binding by clicking this awesome link, even though the link is sort of long](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Here's a real basic demo

```
// a function
var something = function (a, b, c) {
  console.log(a, b, c);
};

// a binding of something with 3 defined args
var b = something.bind(null, 1, 2, 3);

// call b
b();
//=> 1 2 3
```

Behind the scenes, this is basically what's happening

```
// ES6
const myBind = (f, context, ...x) =>
  (...y) => f.call(context, ...x, ...y);

// ES5
var myBind = function(fn, context) {
  var x = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  return function() {
    var y = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0); 
    return fn.apply(context, x.concat(y));
  };
};

var b = myBind(console.log, console, 1, 2, 3);

b();
// => 1 2 3

b(4,5,6)
// => 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

---

**Context?**

Context allows you to dynamically change the `this` of your function. Note you can only bind the context of functions defined with the `function` keyword; arrow functions have a lexical `this` that cannot be manipulated. This is shown for sake of completeness, but I do advise against this kind of program. It's usually better to just use another function parameter instead of relying on dynamic function context, `this`. Supporting context switching like this is to enable object-oriented style in JavaScript. Unless you are using this style, I see no reason to pay attention to context.

```js
const getCanvas = (id) =>
  document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d')

const draw = function (canvas, x = 0, y = 0)
{ canvas.beginPath()
  canvas.strokeStyle = this.color             // `this` refers to context!
  canvas.rect(x, y, this.width, this.height)  // `this` refers to context!
  canvas.stroke()
}

// create two contexts
const contextA =
  { color: 'blue', width: 10, height: 10 }
  
const contextB =
  { color: 'green', width: 10, height: 20 }

// bind the draw function to each context and the canvas
const drawA =
  draw.bind(contextA, getCanvas('main'))
  
const drawB =
  draw.bind(contextB, getCanvas('main'))

// call the bound drawing functions normally
// draw three blue squares
drawA(0, 0)
drawA(20, 0)
drawA(40, 0)

// and one green rect
drawB(80, 0)
```

```html
<canvas id="main"></canvas>
```

**Partial application**

Similar to `bind`ing is [Partial Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application)

> In computer science, partial application (or partial function application) refers to the process of fixing a number of arguments to a function, producing another function of smaller arity.

Here we could make a very simple `partial` helper procedure which helps us accomplish this

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const partial = (f = identity, ...x) =>
  (...y) => f (...x, ...y)

const foo = (...all) =>
  console.log ('array of', all)

partial (foo, 1, 2, 3) (4, 5, 6)
// 'array of', [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

---

**Currying**

[Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) is related to, but not the same as, binding or partial application

> In mathematics and computer science, currying is the technique of translating the evaluation of a function that takes multiple arguments (or a tuple of arguments) into evaluating a sequence of functions, each with a single argument.

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const curry = (f = identity, arity = f.length) => x =>
{
  const next = (xs = []) =>
    xs.length >= arity
      ? f (...xs)
      : x => next ([ ...xs, x ])
  return next ([ x ])
}

const foo = (a, b, c) =>
  console.log ('a', a, 'b', b, 'c', c)

curry (foo) (1) (2) (3)
// 'a' 1 'b' 2 'c' 3

curry (foo) ('choo') ('bye') ()
// 'a' 'choo' 'b' 'bye' 'c' undefined
```

Comment: The link is long, but the contents it points to, not so much! :)

Comment: Thank you alot for the clear explanation after trying hours I finally get it - I had this issue with a callback function within an ajax success callback, always returning this as the window object not the object.
` callbackFunc.bind($self)(cart);`  solved it