# JS Curry function with Recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, currying

Kindly read before you mark it as duplicate.

Im not asking for single curry call.

This functions multiplies, multiplication(4,4,4) //64

```
function multiplication(...args) {

    return args.reduce((accum, val) => accum * val, 1)
}
```

**But** Im trying to achieve something else...

This same function should multiply its curry function parenthesis as well.
e.g.

```
/*
  which return the multiplication of three numbers.
  The function can be called in any of the following forms:

  multiply(2, 3)(4) => 24
  multiply(2)(3, 4) => 24
  multiply(2)(3)(4) => 24
  multiply(2, 3, 4) => 24
*/
```

Kindly help.

After fiddling through a lot of code and reading some stack answers.
Finally I came up with. But it still doesnt satisfy this `multiply(2)(3, 4) => 24`

But works fine for rest of the cases

```
multiply(2,3,4)
multiply(2,3)(4)
multiply(2)(3)(4)

var multiply = function(...args) {
    if (args.length === 3) {
        return args[0] * args[1] * args[2];
    } else {
        return function() {
            args.push([].slice.call(arguments).pop());
            return multiply.apply(this, args);
        };
    }
}
```

while `multiply(2)(3, 4) => 24 fail`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Currying a function that takes infinite arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039020/currying-a-function-that-takes-infinite-arguments)

Comment: @Herohtar kindly mutliply(2,3)(4) and test

Comment: Sorry your self answer was wrong, doesn't mean I know an answer

Comment: @JaromandaX then why down vote bro

Comment: you ASSume I downvoted, but you deleted the answer before I even thought about it - perhaps the downvotes were because your answer was wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX pardon me, but hope someone comes with a near solution. My code suck bad

Comment: your code was 3/4ths the way there, you just have to re-think it I guess

Comment: @JaromandaX actually im stuck at this since last 12hrs and still fiddling. Thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code

```
var multiply = function(...args) {
    if (args.length === 3) {
        return args[0] * args[1] * args[2];
    } else {
        return function() { // ***
            args.push([].slice.call(arguments).pop()); // ***
            return multiply.apply(this, args);
        };
    }
}
```

*** these two lines needed changing, you were almost there, so tantalisingly close in fact

```js
var multiply = function(...args) {
    if (args.length === 3) {
        return args[0] * args[1] * args[2];
    } else {
        return function(...args2) { // ***
            args.push(...args2); // ***
            return multiply.apply(this, args);
        };
    }
}
console.log(multiply(2, 3)(4))
console.log(multiply(2)(3, 4))
console.log(multiply(2)(3)(4))
console.log(multiply(2, 3, 4))
```

ES6 makes it even cleaner

```js
const multiply = (...args) => (args.length === 3) ? args[0] * args[1] * args[2] : (...args2) => multiply(...args.concat(args2));
console.log(multiply(2, 3)(4))
console.log(multiply(2)(3, 4))
console.log(multiply(2)(3)(4))
console.log(multiply(2, 3, 4))
```

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me till the end. Your answer is really good. But I choose @4castle answer

Comment: @4castle answer is definitely better - I just wanted to point out how close your code was

Comment: :) glad to hear

Answer (score 19):

Here's a generalized solution that works by repeatedly calling `bind` until enough parameters have been passed.

```js
function curry(func, arity = func.length) {
  return function (...args) {
    if (args.length >= arity) {
      return func(...args);
    } else {
      return curry(func.bind(this, ...args), arity - args.length);
    }
  };
}

const multiply = curry((a, b, c) => a * b * c);

console.log(multiply(2, 3)(4));
console.log(multiply(2)(3, 4));
console.log(multiply(2)(3)(4));
console.log(multiply(2, 3, 4));
```

Comment: damm thats a perfect FP answer :) love it

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer similar to 4castle's that uses an additional rest parameter instead of `Function.prototype.bind`

```js
const curry = (f, ...xs) => (...ys) =>
  f.length > xs.length + ys.length 
    ? curry (f, ...xs, ...ys)
    : f (...xs, ...ys)
    
const multiply =
  curry ((a, b, c) => a * b * c)

console.log (multiply (2, 3) (4))         // 24
console.log (multiply (2) (3, 4))         // 24
console.log (multiply (2) (3) (4))        // 24
console.log (multiply (2, 3, 4))          // 24
console.log (multiply () () () (2, 3, 4)) // 24
```

But relying upon the `length` property is a function can be a problem when variadic functions come into play – Here, `partial` is easier to understand, explicitly communicates when a function's arguments will not be supplied in entirety, and it works with variadic functions.

```js
const multiply = (x, ...xs) =>
  x === undefined
    ? 1
    : x * multiply (...xs)

const partial = (f, ...xs) =>
  (...ys) => f (...xs, ...ys)

console.log (partial (multiply) (2, 3, 4))    // 24
console.log (partial (multiply, 2) (3, 4))    // 24
console.log (partial (multiply, 2, 3) (4))    // 24
console.log (partial (multiply, 2, 3, 4) ())  // 24

console.log (multiply (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))                     // 5040
console.log (partial (multiply, 2, 3, 4) (5, 6, 7))           // 5040
console.log (partial (partial (multiply, 2, 3), 4, 5) (6, 7)) // 5040
```

Partial application is related to currying, but not exactly the same thing. I write about some of the differences in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41962192/633183) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17711245/633183)

Comment: fwiw, [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) has a strict definition that does not match what you intend for `curry` to do. You might want to call your solution `autoCurry` or something.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal curry function

```
const curry = (fn, ...args) => 
  args.length >= fn.length ? fn(...args) : curry.bind(null, fn, ...args)
```

High Level Explanation:

We want to construct a function, similar in spirit to Thrush ( `f => a => f(a)` ) but with variadic inputs. We want to partially apply input to this function, passing in the curried function `f` for the first parameter and the rest of the parameters needed until the appropriate arity for our function, given by `f.length` is met or exceeded.

Details:

Suppose we have some add function,

```
const add = (a,b,c) => a+b+c
```

and we curry it

```
const curriedAdd = curry( add )
```

Here is what happens:

1. Our curry function receives a function, with no additional arguments (note: we could have passed parameters at the time of the currying, ie `curry( add, 10 )` )
2. The predicate `args.length >= fn.length` is `false` because we provided no `args` and the function has a length of 3
3. We bind to a new copy of curry our original function and all of our arguments (no arguments)

Cool so we basically just get the same function back only now its bound to `curry`

Next we call it thus

```
const inc = curriedAdd(0,1)
```

Now the following happens

1. We invoke the curried function. `curriedAdd` is `add` bound to it as the first parameter (after `this` is set to `null`). It looks like this

   const inc = curry.bind(null,add)(0,1)
2. Here when we invoke curry, `add` is again the first parameter of the function. `args` is now a list of two `[0,1]`.
3. The predicate `args.length >= fn.length` is therefore false because `add.length` is 3 and `args.length` is two.
4. We now bind to yet another fresh copy of `curry` and bind that to `add` with two parameters `[0,1]` spread into bind.

`inc` is not `curry.bind(null, add, 0, 1)`

Cool, so now we call this

```
const six = inc(5)
```

But `inc` is just `curry.bind(null,add,0,1)`

Thus we called `curry` as before. This time `args.length >= fn.length` is `true` and invoke `add` with all three parameters

An important part of this currying function is that the predicate be `args.length >= fn.length` and not `args.length === fn.length` because otherwise this would fail

```
const six = inc(5,undefined)
```

This may seem not important, however, in Javascript you might often do something like this

```
const concatWith = curry( (fn,a,b) => a.concat(fn(b)) )
const collectObjectValues = concatWith(Object.values)
[ {a: 1, b: 2}, {c: 3} ].reduce( collectObjectValues, [] )
// [1,2,3]
```

The `reduce` function passes in a few parameters... a number greater than our expected two (see footnotes). If our curry predicate didn't account for the greater than scenario, this code would break.

Hope this was informative and educational. Enjoy!

Footnotes:

[1] - four to be exact, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 1):

A very basical `curry` function can simply be implemented in JavaScript by using recursion as follows;

```
var curry = f => f.length ? (...a) => curry(f.bind(f,...a)) : f();
```

```js
function multiplyDivide (n,m,o,p){
  return n * m / o * p;
}

var curry = f => f.length ? (...a) => curry(f.bind(f,...a)) : f(),
    cmd   = curry(multiplyDivide);

console.log(cmd(4,5,2,10));     // <- 100
console.log(cmd(4)(5,2,10));    // <- 100
console.log(cmd(4,5)(2,10));    // <- 100
console.log(cmd(4,5,2)(10));    // <- 100
console.log(cmd(4)(5)(2,10));   // <- 100
console.log(cmd(4)(5)(2)(10));  // <- 100
```

However the above `curry` function is valid for functions which take definite number of arguments as we check the `f.length` property which is defined and set at the function's definition. This is a normal functional behaviour since pure functions have a solid type bound with what it takes and what it gives. However JS is loosely typed, and not a pure functional language. It has the freedom of taking indefinitely many arguments.

For indefinitely many arguments designated by the `rest` operator like `(...a)`, the `function.length` property is `0`, enforcing us to use the `arguments.length` to decide where to stop. In this case the curried function will give you a new function every single time for you to be able to enter new arguments up until you invoke it with no arguments finally to get the result.

```js
function prodall(...a){
  return a.reduce((p,c) => p*c);
}

var curry = f => (...a) => a.length ? curry(f.bind(f,...a)) : f(),
    cpa   = curry(prodall);

console.log(cpa(4,5,2,10)());       // <- 400
console.log(cpa(4)(5,2,10)());      // <- 400
console.log(cpa(4,5)(2,10)());      // <- 400
console.log(cpa(4,5,2)(10)());      // <- 400
console.log(cpa(4)(5)(2,10)());     // <- 400
console.log(cpa(4)(5)(2)(10)());    // <- 400
console.log(cpa(4)(5)(2)(10,3)());  // <- 1200
```