# Functional JavaScript: Closure & Recursion. Why does this fail?

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming

desired functionality:

```
mult(3);
 //(x) => 3 * mult(x)
mult(3)(4);
 //(x) => 3 * (4 * mult(x))
mult(3)(4)();
//12
```

attempt:

```
function mult(x){
    if(x === undefined){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return (y => x * mult(y));
    }
}
```

result:

```
mult(3)
//y => x * mult(y)
//looks pretty good

mult(3)()
//3
//exactly what I want so far. 

mult(3)(4)()
//Uncaught TypeError: mult(...)(...) is not a function
```

sure enough,

```
mult(3)(4)
//NaN
```

Yet `mult(3)` looks good and `typeof mult(3) === "function"`.

What gives?
Can I not be this fancy in JS? Any why not?

Comment: Think about what happens when you call `mult(3)(4)`. You are calling `(y => 3 * mult(y))`, where `y` is `4`. What does `mult(4)` return? A function. What does `3 * <a function>` return? `NaN`.

Comment: Probably take a look at the answers here: [JS Curry function with Recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48293642/js-curry-function-with-recursion)

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039020/currying-a-function-that-takes-infinite-arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
mult(3)(4)
```

`mult(3)` yields `y => 3 * mult(y)`.

Thus

```
(y => 3 * mult(y))(4)
```

becomes

```
3 * mult(4)
```

`mult(4)` yields `y => 4 * mult(y)`.

```
3 * (y => 4 * mult(y))
```

is nonsense because you're trying to multiply `3` by a function. This is why you're getting `NaN` here, and `NaN` can't itself be further applied.

---

Possible solution:

```js
function mkmult(acc) {
    return x =>
        x === undefined
            ? acc
            : mkmult(acc * x);
}

const mult = mkmult(1);

console.log(mult(3)());
console.log(mult(3)(4)());
console.log(mult(3)(4)(5)());
```

Comment: Wait actually, my comment was correct. Why are you doing `const mult = mkmult(1)` instead of just defining it as `mult`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Because otherwise `mult()` doesn't give you `1`.

Comment: That wasn't a requirement though?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It's in OP's code. And it makes sense anyway: We can generalize our function to something like a left fold: `function fold_left(acc, op) { return x => x === undefined ? acc : fold_left(op(acc, x), op); }` and in this case `acc` and `x` could even have different types. What you're suggesting is akin to `foldl1`, which 1) forces `acc` and `x` to have the same type and 2) doesn't work on empty lists.

Comment: @melpomene Thank you for showing me the error of my ways. You are my light in the darkness; the lighthouse of truth. Tonight, I will rest easy.

Answer (score 2):

If you think about it, the `mult` should never be passed `undefined` since it represents the "current" or left side of the multiplication. The inner function receiving `y` is the one that should handle providing the result.

```js
function mult(x){
    return y => {
        if (y === undefined) return x;
        else return mult(x * y);
    };
}

console.log(mult(3))
console.log(mult(3)())
console.log(mult(3)(4)())
```

Comment: It's beautiful. Utter beauty. I went with @melpomene 's answer because it clearly showed the error of my sinful ways in addition to how to provide the functionality I desire.

Comment: @doodlemeister, doesn’t work for empty set `mult ()` due to improper assumptions about `x`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way that uses a secondary parameter with a default value

- base case – `x` is undefined, return the accumulator `acc`
- inductive case - `x` is *not* undefined – return a new lambda that asks for the next input `y` and recur using `y` and `acc * x`

```js
const mult = (x, acc = 1) =>
  x === undefined
    ? acc
    : y => mult (y, acc * x)

console.log (mult ())             // 1
console.log (mult (2) ())         // 2
console.log (mult (2) (3) ())     // 6
console.log (mult (2) (3) (4) ()) // 24
```

Personally, I would use a *known* (explicit) empty value rather than relying upon the implicit `undefined`

```js
const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const mult = (x = Empty, acc = 1) =>
  x === Empty
    ? acc
    : y => mult (y, acc * x)

console.log (mult ())             // 1
console.log (mult (2) ())         // 2
console.log (mult (2) (3) ())     // 6
console.log (mult (2) (3) (4) ()) // 24
```

Really though, `mult` as it is defined above is a toy. A more practical implementation would use variadic interface instead of the weirder currying with `()` used to signal a return value

```js
// fixed arity
const mult = (x, y) =>
  x * y

// variadic interface
const multiply = (x = 1, ...xs) =>
  xs.reduce (mult, x)
  
console.log (multiply ())        // 1
console.log (multiply (2))       // 2
console.log (multiply (2, 3))    // 6
console.log (multiply (2, 3, 4)) // 24
```

Comment: I think I'm in love.

Comment: @Paul all of [my answers on recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a633183%20%5brecursion%5d) are answered from a functional programming perspective. I hope you find some of them helpful ^_^